# Using Mr/Miss with first name signifies a close relationship?

Tags: grammar

My Japanese friend asked me if the following is true.

**Mr. Smith (typical way of calling someone in a formal situation)**

**Mr. John (signifies that you have a very close relationship by using the first name instead of their last name)**

**Mr. Smith John (when you want to use the entire name no matter what)**

For me, Mr. Smith John sounds more formal than Mr. Smith, and although Mr. John sounds less formal compared to Mr. Smith, I can't say it means the relationship is very close.

What does everyone think about this? Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but short answer:  Most cultures within the United States don't use "Mr." or "Mrs." or whatever with a first name, ever.  (I think the same is true of Commonwealth English speakers, but one of them should answer.)  Also, we never say "Mr. Lastname Firstname".  (The only time that kind of structure is used is on lists where it's important to alphabetize by last name, where it would be written "Smith, John".)

Comment: @stangdon: As a BrE speaker, I can confirm the same is true.  I have never come across "Mr [firstname]".  ("Mr [firstname] [lastname]" has some currency, although it would rarely be used to address someone directly, and when it is used after "Dear" at the start of a letter, it is considered less correct than "Mr [lastname]".)

Answer (score 3):

In modern English, the following is rarely used, though it has some local or regional currency:

> Mr John

and the following is probably never used:

> <s>Mr Smith John</s>

while these two forms are pretty much identical in usage:

> Mr Smith
>
> Mr John Smith

(although if addressing someone directly, or in the salutation of a letter, "Mr Smith" is preferred).

If you want to use the entire name then you always put the first name before the surname.  (The excepion would be in an index or filing system, but here you probably wouldn't include the title "Mr", and if you did include it, it would go before the first name: "Smith, Mr John".)

It's true that you call someone "Mr Smith" in a formal situation, and that if you know them well you just call them by their first name ("John") - without any title.  But in fact, you don't even have to know them well.  Usually when people meet at a social occasion or gain a new work colleague they begin on first-name terms right from the start.  This wasn't the case a hundred or even fifty years ago, but has been a strong trend over the last few decades.

The titles "Mrs" and "Ms" work the same way.  The titles "Master" and "Miss" may occasionally be used with first names alone, but this usage is considered old-fashioned except in the southern US.

"Sir", on the other hand, if used as a title for a knight (rather than without a name as a polite way of addressing any male), comes before the first name (or sometimes the full name), not the surname: "Sir John Smith" or "Sir John", not "Sir Smith".

Spelling-wise, "Mr", "Mrs", "Ms" and "Dr" are almost always written without full stops in BrE, and with full stops in AmE ("Mr.", "Mrs.", etc).  "Miss", "Master", "Sir" are written without full stops in both BrE and AmE.

Comment: I understood! Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: In the US, you could be addressed as "Miss Anna" in a tone of friendly respect, by someone who had never met you before, especially if you were in the US South, or they had come from the US South or their parents had.  "Old-fashioned" is a relative term. Those who are old-fashioned are often simply traditional in their ways, especially in matters of politeness, and don't think of themselves as driving a horse-and-buggy.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I wasn't trying to be patronising towards the US South.  I simply didn't know that usage was still current.

Comment: @rjpond: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you were. I was suggesting that these speakers don't see themselves as being decidedly anachronistic, as some members of the Society of Friends ("Quakers") do feel when they use the pronouns "thee" and "thou". The Mister/Miss {firstname} practice is quite widespread in the US South (and is still used by speakers from the South who have moved elsewhere) and those speakers feel they are simply being friendly and courteous. They understand their speech to be contemporary.

Comment: @rjpond - I can confirm that the "Mr./Mrs./Miz Firstname" thing is still alive and well in parts of the American South; for example, my nephew called me "Mr. Firstname" before I married his aunt and became "Uncle Firstname"; my wife still calls the mother of her best friend "Miz Firstname".

Comment: "Never" is a strong word. I've seen the Mr. John / Miss Anna format used is in the preschool environment, where I believe it's intended convey an age-appropriate sign of respect. And, as @stangdon says, Mr. Firstname has other pockets of usage as well. As a matter of fact, one of the vendors at my local farmer's market calls me that every week. (It's quirky and unusual here in the Midwestern US; nevertheless, it comes off as cordial and polite.) Change "never" to "rarely" and I'd upvote this answer.

Comment: @rjpond I'm from New Orleans, and I think that courtesy titles with first names express status and are therefore usually a one-way street: Mattie might address Scarlett as "Miss Scarlett," but Scarlet would not reciprocate with any title, but instead use just Mattie's first name. I think this is still very common and unremarkable. It can be a compromise between formality and familiarity, and it also distinguishes forms of address within a family, where everyone might have the same last name but different first names.

Comment: @Chaim: That's interesting information.  On the other hand, according to Stangdon in another comment, most people in the US don't "ever" use it that way.  And I don't think it's ever used that way in the UK.  So without wishing to any way disrespect the way in which it's used where you live, I don't want to rewrite my answer in a way that would risk giving excessive prominence to a minority usage.  In the UK if we heard a foreign visitor say "Mr [firstname]" we would probably assume it was because they hadn't learned English very well rather than because they had learned it in New Orleans.

Comment: My friend, who is a teacher in San Diego public schools, tells me her high school students, mostly Latino, refer to her as Miss or Miss Lindsey. I myself, having lived in Boston and San Francisco most of my life, have never been addressed in such a way.

Comment: @rjpond I understand and I'm not close to taking offence. I guess that I still think of the comments as themselves part of the discussion, although I know (I think) that they're going to be deleted. But the point about usage might help someone watching a television show or movie in which characters spoke this way, and if I saw such a scene it would certainly lead me to think of the characters as differing in rank.

Comment: @rjpond Incidentally Stangdon actually said that we don't say "Mr Trump Donald." I agree; I've never heard that arrangement either.

Comment: @Chaim: Yes, I see what you mean.  I was referring to stangdon's statement in a comment under the original post: "Most cultures within the United States don't use "Mr." or "Mrs." or whatever with a first name, ever."

Comment: In Japanese and Korean (and probably other Asian languages as well), the surname comes first. For example, if Kim Jong Il lived in the U.S., his American name would be Jong-Il Kim.

Comment: @rjpond When I mentioned Mattie and Miss Scarlett, I was thinking of Gone With The Wind. But as I was going about my business the other day, a better example popped into my head: Casablanca. Sam says "Mr. Rick" and "Miss Ilsa," but they always call him just "Sam." The movie was not from Louisiana, but Americans see the deference in Sam's use of courtesy titles, no?